# Auth0 is redirecting to localhost after successful login on react app deployed on netlify

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, netlify

I have deployed my react app using netlify and using auth0 authentication, on the local host, everything was working fine but after deployment and successfully login, the app is getting redirected to localhost:3000/collection, instead, I want it to redirect to https://tubemate/collection.netlify.app after successful login.

```
Application login URL 
https://tubemate.netlify.app
```

```
Allowed callback URLs
https://tubemate/collection.netlify.app
```

```
Allowed logout URLs
https://tubemate.netlify.app
```

```
Allowed web origins
https://tubemate.netlify.app
```

Answer (score 0):

The URLs in Allowed callback URLs should end in `/api/auth/callback`.
So, in your case, change

```
https://tubemate/collection.netlify.app
```

to

```
https://tubemate/collection.netlify.app/api/auth/callback
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback,
```

You should also add the localhost URL to your Allowed callback URLs to be redirected properly when you develop the app locally.